# Extracting sentences from text based on particular pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a small piece of code to extract sentences which contain a particular word from a text document.

Here are the conditions for sentence to qualify:

Sentence must contain the search term.

Sentence must begin with capital letter.

Sentence must end with a period

Sentence must have at least 8 words.

After some research I have found out that fastest way to do it would be using `preg_split()` however I am really new to `regex` therefore I am having difficulties with first two conditions. The last one can be done using if else in `str_word_count()` (I think).

Example:

```
  Der er en lang og bevæget forhistorie bag lov om varsling m.v. i forbindelse med afskedigelser af større omfang. Det er ikke en bureaukratisk lovtekst blandt så mange andre.
```

Search Term:

```
bureaukratisk
```

It will return second sentence `Det er ikke en bureaukratisk lovtekst blandt så mange andre.` because
 it contains our search term and fulfills all three conditions as well

Any help would be highly appreciated

Kind Regards
Ahmar

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Ok. Adding an example

Answer (score 1):

To check if Word is present in sentence use

```
if (strpos($str,'are') !== false) {
    echo 'word is present';
}
```

To check words count

```
str_word_count($str);
```

To check if the first word begins with caps

```
if (strtoupper($str[0]) == $str[0])
{
   echo "match";
}
```

Edit : To get the sentences from a paragraph.

```
$strarr = explode(".",$para)

foreach($strarr as $check)
{

//use the functions i mentioned above here...if it matches print it or concanate it.
}
```

Comment: Problem is that I have large amount of text and I need to extract sentences from it. Your solution is good if I already have the sentences

Answer (score 1):

Your regex string will probably be needing these elements:

```
([A-Z]\w* (.* ){6,} \w+[\.\?\!])

[A-Z] - any capital letter
\w* - zero or more letters
' ' - space
(.* ){6,} - six or more strings of anything ending with a space
' ' - space
\w+[\.\?\!] - at least one letter ending with a . or ? or !
```

I see now that your problem is a little more complex than i thought. But this is a good start. [Check this site out](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

Comment: Is there any way I can find the word I am searching for using regex as well